# How to shift fullcalendar's display time by several minutes

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, momentjs

This could be an embarrassingly easy question but I am new to Moment.js and fullcalendar.

**The goal:** Get fullcalendar to operate on a Moment/DateTime that is a few *minutes* offset from local computer time.

**The rationale:**
We want to synchronize the display time and nowIndicator with the old clocks in a building as opposed to the desktop's time.

**Tried so far:**

```
// Get current offset:
var localOffset = moment().utcOffset();

// Shift by 7 minutes for illustration
localOffset -= 7;

// Set new offset for moment
moment().utcOffset(localOffset);

alert(moment().utcOffset());
```

As of now it prints back the original UTC offset and the nowIndicator matches my system clock. This is using Moment.js 2.19.0.

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ADyson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46680841/3261381) cleared the misconception about a moment object and its scope.

To answer the original problem of shifting FullCalendar's time by an arbitrary amount, use the 'now' option when initializing:

```
// Get current time as moment object and add 7 minute offset
var shiftedTime = moment().add(7, 'minutes');

// Set 'now' option in calendar initialization to new moment object
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    // put your options and callbacks here
    now: shiftedTime,
    defaultView: 'agendaDay',
    nowIndicator: true
});
```

The display of the calendar and the now indicator will be shifted 7 minutes relative to local machine time.

Answer (score 1):

`moment().utcOffset()` is creating a new moment with the default offset. It has nothing to do with the object you previously set an offset on. momentJS works using individual objects which are instantiated by using the `moment()` constructor. It's not a static or global thing.

What you need to do is work with the moment object which you set the offset on:

```
var offsetMoment = moment();
offsetMoment.utcOffset(localOffset);
alert(offsetMoment.utcOffset());
```